# Update quantity of items in cart without pushing entirety of object in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a bit of trouble with this problem. I'm working on the project of an e-commerce application that works on several html pages. I managed to push products through the cart html page,  but I can't seem to find a way to update on this page only the quantity of a product and not push every elements of said product (images, id, etc). Onclick, if product exists, I only want quantity to be updated. Here's the code if any of you can help me out that'd be greatly appreciated.

```js
setItems(kanap);

function setItems(kanap) {

  let cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));

  let imgKanap = kanap.imageUrl;
  let idKanap = kanap._id;
  let colorKanap = colors.value;
  let quantityKanap = parseInt(quantity.value);
  let key = idKanap + ' ' + colorKanap;

  let cartItem = {
    id: idKanap,
    color: colorKanap,
    quantity: quantityKanap,
    kanap: kanap
  };

  if (cart === null) {
    cart = [];
  }

  cart.push(cartItem);

  localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));

  function addProduct(cartItem) {
    var found = false;
    for (key in cartItem) {
      if (cartItem[key].idKanap == idKanap) {
        cartItem[key].quantityKanap += quantityKanap;
        found = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!found) {
      cart.push(cartItem);
    }
  }
  addProduct();
}
```

```html
<div class="item__content__addButton">
  <button id="addToCart" type="submit">Ajouter au panier</button>
</div>

<section class="cart">
  <!-- <section id="cart__items">
         <article class="cart__item" data-id="{product-ID}">
            <div class="cart__item__img">
              <img id ="image" alt="Photographie dun canapé">
            </div>
            <div class="cart__item__content">
              <div class="cart__item__content__titlePrice">
                <h2 class=title></h2>
                <p class =price></p>
              </div>
              <div class="cart__item__content__settings">
                <div class="cart__item__content__settings__quantity">
                  <p class= quantity>Qté : </p>
                  <input type="number" class="itemQuantity" name="itemQuantity" min="1" max="100" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="cart__item__content__settings__delete">
                  <p class="deleteItem">Supprimer</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </article> -->
</section>
```

Comment: where does  `quantity.value` and `colors.value` come from? and why are you calling `addProduct()` with no parameter when it takes 1?

Comment: Hello Andrew, thanks for the reply.

Comment: I just twitched the code a bit for the addProduct mistake I'm sorry. I'm learning front end right now which might explain some of the errors, sorry about that too. I can send you more code if you like, but it overall works meaning products are set to my localStorage, they are displayed in the html cartPage with their options and quantity selected, I just can't figure out how once one product exists I could just add quantity and not "repush" the whole product recreating another row of the item. If I'm unclear please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few approaches you can take, but I am using [.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to look through your cart.

If the `.find()` function finds an item with the same `id` as you're about to add, it will up the quantity of the existing item instead of appending another object with the same ID.

I used a mock local storage since local storage doesn't work in these snippets so just ignore that and use what you've been doing for local storage access.

```js
let mockLS = null;

// guessed at the structure here, you may have something slightly different
const exampleItem = {
  _id: "abc",
  imageUrl: "imageurlexample",
  colors: {
    value: "red"
  },
  quantity: {
    value: 1
  }
}

const exampleItem2 = {
  _id: "abc2",
  imageUrl: "imageurlexample2",
  colors: {
    value: "blue"
  },
  quantity: {
    value: 1
  }
}

function setItems(kanap) {

  //let cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));

  // using a mock localstorage here since it doesn't work within this snippet, use what you currently have instead
  let cart = mockLS;

  let imgKanap = kanap.imageUrl;
  let idKanap = kanap._id;
  let colorKanap = kanap.colors.value;
  let quantityKanap = parseInt(kanap.quantity.value);
  let key = idKanap + ' ' + colorKanap;

  let cartItem = {
    id: idKanap,
    color: colorKanap,
    quantity: quantityKanap
    //kanap: kanap not sure why you want the whole obj here so I left this one out
  };

  if (cart === null) {
    cart = [];
  }

  // here is the case where cart exists and there may be the same item in it
  const itemExists = cart.find(item => {
    if(item.id === idKanap) {
      item.quantity += quantityKanap;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  })

  if (!itemExists) {
    cart.push(cartItem);
  }

  //localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
  mockLS = cart;
}

setItems(exampleItem);
setItems(exampleItem2);
setItems(exampleItem);

console.log(mockLS)
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, It worked! I even could setup appending the same product if only the color was different with 'if (item.id === idKanap && item.color === colorKanap)'. App works smoothly now. I can't up your answer because I just arrived here but it should be up, couldn't find localStorage handling and solution to my problem. Thank you so much for your help and patience.

Comment: no problem, glad you got it all working!